# Return row from an array if contains a value from another array with a different value format

Tags: php, arrays, search, compare

I need to compare 2 different format arrays. The goal is to print from file1 only that rows which contain value from file2.

I suppose that I have to load both files into 2 arrays and compare it. I tried `array_intersect()`, `in_array()` and `array_key_exists()`, nothing works for me.

Here is the example of data files:

File 1:

```
2.26.81.0,4,10146128,10165054
82.132.227.75,7,10146130,10166530,10166093
91.206.0.35,10,10150898,10165809
88.145.18.102,3,10169097,10141126,21729395
```

File 2:

```
10146128
10146130
```

Result should looks like this:

```
2.26.81.0,4,10146128,10165054
82.132.227.75,7,10146130,10166530,10166093
```

I have loaded both files in 2 arrays and I need to compare them now

```
$bought = fopen('f_data.csv', 'r');
$visited = fopen('l_data.csv', 'r');


$line = fgets($bought);
    while(! feof($bought)) {    
        $line = fgets($bought);
        $bought_f[] = $line;
    }

$line2 = fgets($visited);
    while(! feof($visited)) {   
        $line2 = fgets($visited);
        $visited_f[] = $line2;
    }
```

Comment: Simon, I think the question would be better received if you could write it with focus on the part you're having trouble with. Right now it scans as "student trying to get us to do his assignment." You could ask for example, "how do I compare two arrays?" and leave out the details of the overall assignment. Targeted questions are more likely to have general value to the community, as well.

Comment: Thanks, There is a lot of same questions about how do I compare two arrays but every questions is the same and in 90% the answer is = intersect. But you'r right.

Comment: How many lines in the files?

Comment: file 1 - 2,3mil and file 2 - 900k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you used didn't work because you converted the first file in an array putting each line into an array element, but since each line not a value but a list of values you should create a two-dimensional array (an array of arrays), so each array element contains just a value. For example you can do that using [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
// getting an array with an element for each line
$file1=file("file1.csv");
$length=count($file1);
// converting each line in an array of the comma-separated values
for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++) {
  $file1[$i]=explode(",",$file1[$i]);
}
//for file2 using file() is enough as each line only contains one value
$file2=file("file2.csv");
```

In this way `$file1[0][0]` is`2.26.81.0`, `$file1[0][1]` is `4`, `$file1[0][2]` is `10146128` and so on. Then, you have several options, the most basic one is using a double loop:

```
foreach ($file1 as $line) {
  foreach ($file2 as $value) {
    // code for checking if $value is contained in $line and store/print the result 
  }
}
```

Depending of what you need using [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for comparison and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for converting the line back to a comma-separated string would do the job.

Also note that if the first file can contain several values of the second file in the same line you can get duplicate results, in that case the solution would be stop checking the values of the second array as soon as you get a match.